# Find all 3 digit numbers, that are coprime with 30

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

At first I found prime factors of 30, which are 2,3 and 5
I need to find all numbers, that are not divisable by 2, 3 and 5.
In other words, $|A|$ is all numbers divisable by 2, $|B|$ is all numbers divisable by 3, $|C|$ is all numbers divisable by 5, I need to find $\overline{|A \cup B \cup C|}$.
$|A \cup B \cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A \cap B| - |B \cap C| - |A \cap C| + |A \cap B \cap C|$
$|A| = 9*10*5=450$ (all numbers divisable by 2)
$|B| = 3*10*10=300$ (all numbers divisable by 3)
$|C| = 9*10*2=180$ (all numbers divisable by 5)
$|A \cap B| = 3*10*5=150$ (all numbers divisable by 2 and 3)
$|B \cap C| = 3*10*2=60$ (all numbers divisable by 3 and 5)
$|A \cap C| = 9*10*1=90$ (all numbers divisable by 2 and 5)
$|A \cap B \cap C| = 3*10*1=30$ (all numbers divisable by 2,3 and 5/ divisable by 30)
$|A \cup B \cup C|=450+300+180-150-60-90+30=660$
So in total we have $|U| - |A \cup B \cup C|=900-660=240$

Is this correct solution? (I'm comparing mine with another solution with another answer).And is there a more simple way to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer is correct.  And yes, I think there is a simpler way to solve this problem.  Note that within any $30$ consecutive integers, exactly $\varphi(30)=8$ will be relatively prime to $30$.  Since you have $900=30\cdot 30$ consecutive integers ($100$ to $999$), exactly $30\cdot 8=240$ will be relatively prime to $30$.